# Difficulties proving the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am currently studying for my exams in Analysis, and came across a problem that I am not quite sure how to solve.
It asks to check whether a given series converges or not, and if it does, what value it converges to.

The specific series I am having troubles with is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^k}{(k!)^2}$$

I have tried applying the ratio test, but got stuck. This is what I have tried so far:

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty} \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| &= \lim_{k\to\infty} \left| \frac{\frac{(k+1)^{k+1}}{((k+1)!)^2}}{\frac{k^k}{(k!)^2}} \right| \\
\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{k+1}(k!)^2}{k^k((k+1)!)^2} \\
\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)(k+1)^k \times k! \times k!}{k^k \times (k+1)! \times (k+1)!} \\
\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)(k+1)^k \times k! \times k!}{k^k \times k!(k+1) \times k!(k+1)} \\
\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)^k}{(k+1)k^k} \\
\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(k+1)^{k-1}}{k^k}
\end{align}$$

But I am unsure how to continue from here, let alone how to calculate the converging value, since I cannot yet simply evaluate the term, as it would resolve to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. I might be able to use l'Hospital's rule, but I don't see how that would benefit me, since the resulting terms are even worse to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work is correct so far. Let's write: $$\frac{(k+1)^{k-1}}{k^k}=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k-1}$$

You should be aware that: $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$From which it follows that the above ratio tends to: $$(\lim_{k\to\infty}1/k)\cdot e=0$$

Hence: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=0$$

As a general rule, factorials beat powers.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that I could simply pull out the $\frac{1}{k}$. Unfortunately, I still haven't managed to find out what value the series converges to, do you maybe have a hint about how to start?

Comment: @Keroten To what value it converges? Wolfram Alpha doesn’t know and I’m pretty sure no one knows. I have never seen a successful evaluation of a series involving summands of $k^k$. You could try asking this as a separate question but I doubt there is an answer

Comment: That is really weird, and also why I am stumped, considering this was on an actual exam I found. This makes it seem like it shouldn't be all that difficult, let alone impossible, but I don't even know where to begin in finding the value of the limit.

Comment: Actually, it turns out I misread the assignment: there were two series, this being the second one, and only for the first one did you have to calculate the limit.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

We have $${(2k)!\over (k!)^2}={2k\choose k}<4^k$$
Thus
$${k^k\over (k!)^2}<{4^kk^k\over (2k)!}={4^k\over k!}{k^k\over (k+1)(k+2)\cdot\ldots \cdot 2k}\le {4^k\over k!}$$
The series with terms $4^k/k!$ is convergent by the ratio test.

**Solution 2:**

This solution is a sort of overkill. We have $$e^x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x^n\over n!}\quad(*)$$ Thus $\displaystyle e^k\ge {k^k\over k!}$ and $\displaystyle {k^k\over (k!)^2}\le {e^k\over k!},$ which in view of $(*)$ implies  $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {k^k\over (k!)^2}\le  \sum_{k=1}^\infty {e^k\over k!}= e^e-1$$